# Branch.io event not appears in Google Analytics 4 dashboard

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, branch.io, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I have been integrating the Branch SDK and Google Analytics 4 into my app to support mobile attribution. I need to send Branch.io events to Google Analytics 4 dashboard and I have followed the documentation outlined in https://help.branch.io/partners-portal/docs/google-analytics-4#properties-sent-to-google-analytics as Branch.io sending the correct webhook logs to GA4 but I am still not seeing test data appear in my Google Analytics 4 dashboard.

[image: Branch WebHook]

Comment: can you paste/add the full webhook request URL? I can only see partial from this image

Comment: "https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect?firebase_app_id=<FIREBAE_ADD_ID HERE>&api_secret=<API_SECRET_HERE>"

Comment: This is not a valid MP hit, it does not contain event information and other basic information. Use this tool to see how the MP hit is built for GA4: https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/event-builder/